# Google translate on my website

Tags: html, google-translate

I'm trying to embed Google Translate snippet in my website, but for some reason it is not even displayed.
I go here:
[Google tools](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools)

Copy this:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
         pageLanguage: 'en'
      }, 'google_translate_element');
   }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Paste it to my webpage.
And I don't see it there.

What am I missing?
Some HTML maybe?

Comment: Could you provide us a link to your website?

Comment: Actually, I haven't uploaded it yet, I've been doing all the work locally, on my computer.
Could this be the reason?

Comment: Here is the page where Google Translate works fine:
http://www.pkdiet.com/
I recreated this page locally on my computer and I can still see the Google Translate select element, but it's empty.

Comment: If you're doing this locally, how do you think Google can access the _local_ website and translate it? Thing is, it can't, so you will have to upload the code to a webserver, and then I am pretty sure the translation-tool will magically work!

Comment: Mrtn flies in through the window and (probably) saves the day!

Comment: You are SO right!
I am SO absent minded! :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example. I think you are missing "&ug=section&hl={LANGUAGE}" parameters:

My Page 
    
 
 
    Тестирование

```
<script>
function googleSectionalElementInit() {
  new google.translate.SectionalElement({
    sectionalNodeClassName: 'translate',
    controlNodeClassName: 'translate_control',
    background: '#f4fa58'
  }, 'google_sectional_element');
}
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maxim75/H3Wkr/ - working example

Comment: can we convert multiple language with two or more button like translate to eng translate to hindi etc...
In your example there is some div close with p tag is there any specific reason??

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML, the 'control' class element needs to be nested in the 'section' element. :)